# Design IIR Butterworth filter using bilinear transform

Tags: filter-design

Write listing in MATLAB which design a low-pass IIR filter basis on Butterworth (Rp=2dB, Rr=40dB, fp=1000 Hz, fr=1300 Hz, fs=5000 Hz) as a prototype and using bilinear transform without built-in functions. Control the point(fr,Rr). Plot the response characteristic (linear scale, and dBs scale).

[image: formulas]

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Do you have a question? You seem to have written some statements without actually asking a question. And the question you do appear to (not) be asking is: write me some code to a specification... which is going to close this question very quickly.

Comment: boy, i dunno if i want to explain to Bartosz how to reinvent this wheel.  one thing i might point out that he/she might want to prewarp the passband edge $f_p$ and stopband edge $f_r$ before determining $M$.  especially with a low-pass filter.  bilinear transform actually makes the LPF cutoff harder than does the analog prototype.  sometimes you can get away with an order $M$ lower you would with the analog prototype.